# How to use rxjs to cancel out of a series of confirmation dialogs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a series of confirmation dialogs that I need to present to the user. As soon as a 'no' answer is given, I want to cancel out of the series of dialogs.

Seemed to me that the way to do this is like this:

```
from([dialog1,dialog2,dialog3]).pipe(
    concatMap(dialog => {
        return dialogService.confirm()
    }),
    toArray()
).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

Unfortunately, a 'no' answer doesn't cancel the series, and the result is an array representing the results of each dialog response rather than just getting the last response.

Is there a better rxjs way of handling this situation?

I used the suggestion from @Eldar:

```
from([dialog1,dialog2,dialog3]).pipe(
    concatMap(dialog => dialogService.confirm()),
    takeWhile(result => result==true),
    toArray()
).subscribe(result => console.log(result))
```

...which helped, but I'm still getting an array as the final result rather than the last value (e.g., `[true, true, false]`, when I want just `true` or `false`). So, it still feels clunky.

Comment: You can use operators like takeWhile and takeUntil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `toArray`, you can use `reduce` to emit a single boolean when the stream completes.

```js
from([dialog1, dialog2, dialog3]).pipe(
    concatMap(dialog => dialogService.confirm()),
    takeWhile(result => result==true, true),
    reduce((_, result) => result),
).subscribe()
```

Notice for `takeWhile` you need to pass `true` for the ['inclusive'](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile) parameter otherwise, the first `false` value will not get emitted.

Since you just want to emit the most recent result, we don't need to use the accumulator in `reduce`, we just return the current result.

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76045735?devtoolsheight=80&file=index.ts).